# Why do people who find it hard to hear say they are "hard of hearing"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

"I am hard of seeing" or "I am hard of walking" are just never used.  How did people come to call semi-deafness "hard of hearing"?

Especially, why is "hard of" used?  I could understand "weak of hearing", but why "hard"?

Comment: Google NGrams does report examples for [hard of seeing](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hard+of+seeing&year_start=1200&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @JoseK: Yes, and graphing ["seeing" against "hearing"](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hard+of+seeing%2Chard+of+hearing&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) kinda proves my point.

Comment: May be *hard of hearing* stuck on because it [appeared in Shakespeare](http://www.bartleby.com/70/2121.html)

Comment: @drm65: I have a (good) guess, but no references, so I'll avoid posting although I'm pretty sure of it... If nothing comes up or if I find something more, I'll post it.

Comment: @Jose: I figured it might have been. . . although there it seems to mean something along the lines of _difficult to hear_.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's "hard for me to hear" you with all this racket going on in the background. Sometimes it's "hard to tell/make out" what you're saying. She has difficulty (it's hard) in hearing, etc..

Comment: The best take on this was in an episode of *Seinfeld*. The valet that parked Jerry's car had terrible b.o. When Elaine and Jerry get back in the car, Jerry asks, "Do you smell that?" And Elaine says, "What am I, *hard of smelling*?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common construction from Middle English that is used not-so-unextensively as you'd think:

*Fleet of foot*.

*Yorkshire born and Yorkshire bred,
Strong of arm and thick of head.*

Etc.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't my question so much how the "hard" came to be applied to the "of" construction.

Comment: I don't think there's a special reason for "hard' to be used in this way -- It's an adjective, so it fits into the adjective-"of"-noun template.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question. [Etymonline's](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hard) entry on *hard* explains that the phrase *hard of hearing* "preserves obsolete M.E. sense of *having difficulty in doing something*." This doesn't explain why it is only used for partial deafness. Maybe its alliteration lent it such long life.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "hard of seeing" is in use.  It was coined by the late, Dr. Lorraine June Marchi Fastie.  [click here to read about her](http://www.legacy.com/obituaries/sfgate/obituary.aspx?n=lorraine-marchi-fastie&pid=149015669)

Answer (score 0):

What might have been omitted in the explanations here is the alliteration of the phrase, "hard of hearing". This does not address the 'hard' or the 'of' but it does point to how the musicality of the phrase strikes the ear. Therefore its longevity over the phrase "hard of seeing".